# Swift set button constraints with an image

Tags: ios, swift

I just have a simple button I am trying to add an image to but no matter what I do with the constraints the image always just changes the size of the button to match the image size. Do I need to change the image size to match that of the button, or is there something I am missing? I have tried using this constraints modifier to set a fixed width and height but it seems to not do anything. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcAZK.jpg

I know this is basic but I cant seem to find any available resources.

Comment: Is it setup in storyboard? If so, can you post your Attributes

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of UIButton and override the imageRect method and pass whatever the image rect you need. Button will now have whatever size you want no matter how big or small image is.

In code below I am setting the image starting from (0,0) of button. Image will take the height of button and width relative to button's height.

```
import UIKit

class MyTestButton: UIButton {

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentRect.height * 2.285, height: contentRect.height)
    }
}
```

**Bonus :**

You can set the button title's rect as well, by overriding

```
override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // return the rect you want
 }
```

Use these to methods to set the frame of title image and text the way u want :) Now add whatever the constraint u want to add to button and button will follow :)